# How to convert commands recorded in selenium IDE to Java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

Is there any application or simple way to convert all the commands recorded by `Selenium IDE` to `Java (Selenium WebDriver)`?
It would be a lot more easier and would save a lot of time.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to convert whole code to Java at a time? or, Do you like to convert individual command one by one?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In my Selenium IDE version 2.4.0 it is easy as pie:

1. Record testcase in Selenium IDE
2. Click File - Export Test Case As - Java / JUnit4 / WebDriver
3. Save File as .java

And here you go! Your testcase is converted to WebDriver ;)

Comment: If you want to see a good tutorial for this just take a look: 
http://elementalselenium.com/tips/6-export-from-selenium-ide

Answer (score 14):

Update: Starting from SeleniumIDE 3.x unfortunately both functions mentioned in previous answers "Export" and "Options->Format" were removed (reason is the porting to the new WebExtensions format of Firefox and Chrome).

But a current alternative is [Katalon Recorder](https://www.katalon.com/resources-center/blog/katalon-automation-recorder/) which is available for [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/katalon-recorder-selenium/ljdobmomdgdljniojadhoplhkpialdid?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon) and [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/katalon-automation-record/).

Katalon Recorder has an "Export" button and can export 3 Selenium formats, with TestNG, with JUnit and even with Thoughtworks WebDriverBackedSelenium and JUnit.

Just press "Export", choose your format, than "Copy to Clipboard" or "Save as file...".

Comment: Nevertheless, since 2020 at least @imaginabit's answer works by clicking on the test's little side menu (three vertical dots) and choosing "Export".

Answer (score 7):

In my Selenium IDE version 2.4.0

```
Record a new test case with the help of Selenium IDE

 1) Click on File a primary nav bar
 2) check drop down is displayed
 3) select on Export test case as 
 4) Check you can convert selenium test case in any language EG: Java / JUnit4 / WebDriver

Save File as .java
Your testcase is converted to WebDriver
```

check image [image]

Comment: In Selenium IDE 2.9.1 Java / TestNG / WebDriver has been implemented

Comment: Chrome version doesn't have it.

Comment: In the latest version of the IDE I don't see any of the menu options?  Am I loosing my mind?

Comment: @Daryl Don't see it either. Was able to successfully run previous version if IDE on FF 54.

Comment: you can see it by right click on the test case
https://selenium.dev/selenium-ide/img/docs/code-export/right-click.png

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 ways to convert a recorded tests(HTML format) into Java code in Selenium IDE:

***1st way:*** To see the Java code directly in Selenium IDE

1. Go to Options -> Options...
2. At "Selenium IDE Options" window: Check the check box for "Enable experimental features" and click OK button
3. Options -> Format -> Java / JUnit4 / WebDriver
4. Click OK button from "JavaScript Application" pop up -> You will see the desired Java source code for your recorded tests

***2nd way:*** By exporting recorded test case(HTML format) into java file:

1. Record your tests in HTML format by using Selenium IDE
2. File -> Export Test Case As -> Java / JUnit4/ WebDriver
3. Save the file (it would be saved as .java)
4. Open the java file you saved in any text editor or IDE such as, Notepad++, Notepad, Wordpad, Eclipse, IntelliJ IDEA etc. (You can see the expected Java Selenium source code)

There is another way to convert Selenium IDE command individually to any language. The following steps for java:

1. Open Firefox -> Open Selenium IDE
2. Record some steps of your test
3. In Selenium IDE: Go to Options | Clipboard Format and select Java / TestNG / WebDriver
4. Right click any command in Selenium IDE you recorded -> Click Copy
5. Paste in any editor (such as NotePad, Wordpad etc. OR any IDE you are using such as eclipse, IntelliJ IDEA)
6. The command will be pasted as Java format

Note: In similar way you can convert individual Selenium IDE command to C#, Python and many more you want.

Comment: In Selenium IDE 2.9.1 Java / TestNG / WebDriver has been implemented.

Comment: Selenium IDE 3: Export/conversion option is absent

Answer (score 3):

Im using selenium ide firefox extension and find this looking for how to export tests to javascript

I found you can export to C# NUnit, C# xUnit, Java JUnit, JavaScript Mocha, Python ,pytest, Ruby RSpec just right click on the test and a menu with export options appears

some times you can't find the easy way

Comment: Thanks, this works at least in Firefox 95.0. Likely also in every version since your post. What was the current Selenium IDE then, I wonder, and when did this export functionality return, if ever absent.