# Selenium IDE - convert html to junit automatically

Tags: java, selenium, gradle, spring-boot, selenium-ide

I have application(Spring boot, Gradle).
Now I need to find a possible and easier way to convert HTML scenario (created with Selenium IDE) to JUnit tests automatically (maybe run some Gradle task). 
I found some plugins like - https://github.com/willwarren/selenium-maven-plugin (based on Maven) and https://github.com/nextinterfaces/selenium4j (based on Ant).

How can I add this plugin to my application? Is it posible to add maven or ant based plugin to gradle based application? 
Maybe some plugins for gradle also exist?
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: In selenium IDE, there's an option to [export as JUnit test](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19358183/how-to-convert-commands-recorded-in-selenium-ide-to-java)

Answer (score 0):

In the selenium IDE, you will find the option in File menu to export your test case in multiple languages.

Goto: File> Export Test Case As> Java / JUnit 4 / Web Driver

Here's a screenshot showing this:
[Export test case in Selenium to Java JUnit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/latc3.png)