# Convert JUnit code into selenium ide HTML

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

Is there a way to convert selenium webdriver java code into selenium ide HTML? I have a test case in java but I want it to run on selenium ide. Can anybody help?

Comment: As far as i know answer is NO.

Comment: @NarendraRajput Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

**Selenium IDE allows two conversation :**

1. Export recorded script. As per this link [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19358183/how-to-convert-commands-recorded-in-selenium-ide-to-java)

You can export test cases from selenium IDE to other format.

2. For convert code in Selenium IDE source tab [Reference](http://www.softwaretestingclass.com/how-to-create-selenium-webdriver-test-using-selenium-ide-selenium-tutorial/)

Here you have option to convert already recorded script and view.

> Now answer : As per my experience and research user can not give selenium webdriver code in selenium IDE and convert it. Just record same steps as written and save it.

Comment: As per current situation , No.