# How to record test case in IE using selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-ide

Hi guys is there a possibility to record the test case using Selenium IDE & convert recorded script to Java WebDriver format & execute the automated test script using Eclipse....

NOTE: I AM USING INTERNET EXPLORER.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert commands recorded in selenium IDE to Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19358183/how-to-convert-commands-recorded-in-selenium-ide-to-java)

Comment: bro I want to record my screen test step by step but how?Selenium IDE is for chrome and firefox only

Comment: bro... you record the scenario in FF, export it to Java/WebDriver and run it against IE. What's the problem? Read the linked Q&As and do some research. There's a lot of documentation on this.

Comment: @JeffC This only works if your application is compatible with Chrome and Firefox..

Answer (score -1):

You can only record the testcase with the Selenium IDE if you use Firefox or Chrome.

You can run your tests however afterwards with IE if you want to, using the [Selenium IE Driver](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver)